# IBAction button change color?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton, ibaction

I have created a button in interface builder and set its type as custom. I want to change the background color of the button based on the button's tag when the view loads. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button added to Xib, tag set to 1.

View header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

In interface builder, bound myButton to button.

Then programmatically in viewDidLoad, conditionally set based on tag value:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([myButton tag] == 1)
    {
        [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I do have another question - if i have 20 buttons and i want to apply the same snippet of code to them how can i? IBOutlet only lets me connect one object. I could create 20 different IBOutlets but there is probably a easier way to do this?

Comment: IBOutlet just lets you get access to the object that's created as part of your XIB.  Your options are (1) create 20 buttons in the XIB, have outlets, add each to an NSMutableArray and then iterate and assign in code ... or, (2) Create them completely programmatically, have them in an array and have a block that iterates and sets the color.  HTH